# Requests are slow after scaling after warmup

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, warm-up

When my server scales out for almost 1 minute all my requests are slow.
I have warm up in place and I can see that my DB calls and BlobStorage calls are very fast (in total less than 200 ms) but the request takes a lot more (for example 15 second)

Also, looking at the dependencies all calls to the dependencies comes back really fast but there is a big gap between them.

What can I do to fix it?

### Requests

[image: Requests]

### Dependencies for a slow request at 6:10:48

[image: Dependencies]

- The ARR Affinity is set to off
- Always On is on

Comment: Hi, today we are still having this issue. Running .NET Core 3.1 with multiple warmup calls (Database, Key vault, Cache and DI initialization). Do you have this resolved?

Comment: @JonHendrix  Recently there was a bug on App service that made it have cold warm ups. If you have bounded host names with wildcards add 1 more with 1 specific host name

Comment: thanks. We already have this in place. So we need to look further for other causes and solutions